# Как настроить редирект в lighttpd?

Tags: redirect

Нужно настроить редирект в lighttpd.
С www.site.com на www.site.com/main/1/

Делал так:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www.site.com" {  url.redirect += (    "^/$" => "http://www.site.com/main/1/"  )}$HTTP["host"] =~ "^site.com" {  url.redirect += (    "^/$" => "http://www.site.com/main/1/"  )}$HTTP["host"] == "www.site.com" {    ...стандартные настройки сервера...}
```

После этих настроек с site.com редиректит нормально, но с www.site.com ни в какую, хотя с www мне нужно больше редирект.

Спасибо кто откликнется.

Answer (score 1):

Сделай так:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^site.com" {  url.redirect += (    "^/$" => "http://www.site.com/main/1/"  )}$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www.site.com" {  url.redirect += (    "^/$" => "http://www.site.com/main/1/"  )}
```